# Core Bluetooth: CBPeripheral disconnects unknowingly and not getting any call to didDisconnectPeripheral

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I have 3 ViewControllers.
1)Home VC
2) Scan VC
3) Connect VC

Steps:
From Home VC, I push to Scan VC for scanning the available BLE Devices.

**Scan VC:** I have all the BLE Communication code here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            AppConstants.sharedInstance.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil) // created global Instance for central Manager and assigned it here
    }
```

Above will call `centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager)` Where I am checking all the state for BLUETOOTH. And if,

```
case .poweredOn:
            btnRefresh.isEnabled = true
            print("central.state is .poweredOn...")

            startScan()
        }
```

then I Scan for the Devices.

Once I get my device, I connect to it from list of scanned devices,

Then I successfully Connect to that Device it goes to **Connect VC.**

Till here everything is great.

But real problem starts when

1) I pop from **Connect VC to Scan VC** and then again Pop to **HOMEVC** And

2) Then I again push from **Home VC** to **Scan VC**

**Scan VC:** This will call and assign the Delegate to my global CentralManager and as soon as it assign the delegate again, It disconnects the previous connection. (Even I don't get any **didDisconnectPeripheral** Call)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            AppConstants.sharedInstance.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil) // Here when I come again it disconnects old connection.
    }
```

I don't know what's the issue. I am not getting any errors. 
Please Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Worries. I found my way to workaround. Thanks to @Natrajan for giving me some idea about it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            if AppConstants.sharedInstance.centralManager == nil{
                AppConstants.sharedInstance.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                centralManagerDidUpdateState(AppConstants.sharedInstance.centralManager!)
            } 
}
```

This serves my purpose and I can Check the Bluetooth State and Scan accordingly (Everytime pushing to the Scan VC)

Yuppieee...
:)

Answer (score 1):

I think, Since you are reassigning `CBCentralManager` to `AppConstants.sharedInstance.centralManager` in `viewDidLoad`, `CBCentralManager` is getting destroyed and disconnected.

Also As it's destroyed, it is not returning any delegate callbacks.

So Can you try to initialize the `CBCentralManager` only once as like below and disconnect when required?

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if AppConstants.sharedInstance.centralManager == nil{

            AppConstants.sharedInstance.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: nil, queue: nil)
        }

        AppConstants.sharedInstance.centralManager.delegate = self
    }
```

Comment: YES, I tried like it but then it checks for the BLUETOOTH state for first time only. 
When I come back to this screen, It doesn't call this centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) method again. And I want to check and scan for the BLE everytime I come to SCAN VC.

Comment: Yes, It won't call the delegate method again unless any changes in `CBCentralManager`'s state. But you can get the current state of  `CBCentralManager` using `AppConstants.sharedInstance.centralManager.state` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Brother. I appreciate it.